# Как правильно сделать проверочную запись md5(python)

Tags: php, python, хеширование, md5

Добрый день. Потребовалось сделать проверочную запись `hash md5`, есть пример на `php`

Пример формирования проверочной записи для языка php:

```
$hash = md5($page.$action.$apikey)
```

Но т.к я не пишу на `php`, а использую `python`, потребовалось немного поменять код, либа `hashlib` показала как можно шифровать, но не проверять запись. Можете ли вы подсказать, как реализовать пример выше с помощью `python`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5297483/5741205

Answer (score 0):

[md5() php-функция](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.md5.php) возвращает хеш в виде 32-символьного шестнадцатеричного числа. В Питоне:

```py
import hashlib

h = hashlib.md5('яблоко'.encode()).hexdigest()
# -> '1afa148eb41f2e7103f21410bf48346c'
```